# PrintWriter appending lines after every execution (Not refreshing the file)

Tags: java, file, csv, filewriter, printwriter

I am pretty new to java, I am writing data to a file. My code looks like this:

```
File file= new File("model/file.csv");
FileOutputStream writer=null;
try {
    writer = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
PrintWriter pw=null;
pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
try {
    for (int j=0;j< 24; j++)
    pw.format("%.3f%n",MyData);
}
finally {
    pw.close();
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But when I run the program for the second time my output file looks like this:

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Ok I figured that

```
 writer = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

means that it appends, but I want the file to be refreshed and not contain data from the previous program execution. And also flush doesn't help.

Comment: So providing `true` means it appends. What is the opposite of that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: Then it would print just one value to the file, for example my output: 1

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Did you try it? (The argument only applies when you first open the file. You're only opening it once...)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: To print 1 2 3 4 again, but not appended to the previous output.

Comment: so as I can understand you will write in the file once?

Comment: Yes, in simple words I do not want to overwrite the file from the previous program execution. I want new data to be written starting from the first line after every execution cycle.

Comment: So you have to update your for loop clause each time. I guess if you wanna have different value. Do I make sense?

Comment: Well actually the for loop makes no difference either, even if I was just writing data without it, it would still append. I think the problem lies somewhere with creation of the file.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want the file to be truncated completely before your next write?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Providing `false` as the second argument does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion is to use `FileWriter` like

Following syntax creates a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)
```

set boolean to `false` to indicate you do not want to do the append.

**for example**:

```
   try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("login.txt", false));) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            out.println(i);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

[Read About The Try-With-Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [FileOutputStream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) shows that the append param will... append to the file! So change it to false, or leave it off.

```
writer = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: Doesn't help, the I would get only one value for my output
For example it would look like this: 

1

Rest of the other numbers are missing. (2,3,4)